# R version of scatter3 (matlab)

Tags: r, matlab

Is there an equivalent function in R of the function scatter3 in matlab? scatterplot3d lacks some of the parameters.

Example: (In matlab)

```
    N = 2^11; 
    t = rand(1,N);
    t = sort(4*pi*sqrt(t))'; 
    z = 8*pi*rand(N,1); 
    x = (t+.1).*cos(t);
    y = (t+.1).*sin(t);

    cmap = jet(N);
    scatter3(x,y,z,20,cmap);
```

[image: Graphical representation to be reproduced in R]

The "equivalent" in R does not give the same kind of representation:

```
    N = 2^11 
    t = runif(N)
    t = sort(4*pi*sqrt(t))
    z = 8*pi*runif(N) 
    x = (t+0.1)*cos(t)
    y = (t+0.1)*sin(t)

    library(gplots)
    cmap = rich.colors(N)

    library(scatterplot3d)
    par(mfrow = c(1,1))
    scatterplot3d(x,y,z, color = cmap, cex.symbols = 3, type = "b")
```

[image: Not the nice graphical representation as in matlab]

Comment: Which parameters does it lack? Please [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: also check out the `plot3D` package, and [this presentation](http://pj.freefaculty.org/guides/Rcourse/plot-3d/plots-3d.pdf)

Comment: still not clear what you are missing. The plots are viewed from different default angles and the colour map is different, but otherwise ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker The best I can get is by using an angle of 90 between the x and y-axis. I know these are the same graphs. I am trying to get that "view from the top" of the xy plane. It will make viewing clustering algorithm performances easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** to my surprise, you're right that `scatterplot3d` really doesn't have this flexibility (I would have sworn it did). However, a very slight hack lets you do this with `persp()`.

Set up data (thanks for the reproducible example).

```
N <- 2^11 
t <- runif(N)
t <- sort(4*pi*sqrt(t))
z <- 8*pi*runif(N) 
x <- (t+0.1)*cos(t)
y <- (t+0.1)*sin(t)
```

A color map that matches the one you've got pretty closely:

```
cmap <- colorRampPalette(c("blue","cyan"))(N)
```

The trick is to set up an empty `persp()` with the right dimensions, setting the `phi`  and (optionally) `theta` and `r` parameters to set the viewing parameters. (`phi=90` will view the x-y plane.) Then use `trans3d()` with the transformation matrix that's returned by `persp()` to plot your points.

```
## empty plot
pp <- persp(range(x),range(y),matrix(c(min(z),max(z),0,0),2),
      col=NA,border=NA,phi=90,zlab="")
## plot:
points(trans3d(x,y,z,pp),col=cmap)
```

[image]

This doesn't look like your plot, because (I think) you have isometric perspective enabled.  To get this, move the view point a long distance from the object (i.e., set `r` to a large value):

```
pp2 <- persp(range(x),range(y),matrix(c(min(z),max(z),0,0),2),
      col=NA,border=NA,phi=90,r=1000)
points(trans3d(x,y,z,pp2),col=cmap)
```

[image]

(forgot to turn off the ugly `z` label on this one).

On the other hand, if all you want to do is view the points in the x-y plane, why not just use plain old `plot()` and ignore the z coordinate???

```
plot(x,y,cex=5,col=cmap)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Thats a neat trick. Ignoring the z axis and going for an xy plot does the job but I will need to plot all dimensions later and the perps() function will come in handy. Thanks again for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

With just slight modification of a line of your code, you may like the spiral drawn:

```
scatterplot3d(x,z,y, color = cmap, cex.symbols = 1.2, pch=19, type = "b")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in interactivity and mirroring what is availble in Matlab, have a look at the `scatter3d` function offered via `car` package.

*The code available through the help section:*

```
require(car)
if(interactive() && require(rgl) && require(mgcv)){
    scatter3d(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan)
    Sys.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds
    scatter3d(prestige ~ income + education | type, data=Duncan)
    Sys.sleep(5)
    scatter3d(prestige ~ income + education | type, surface=FALSE,
              ellipsoid=TRUE, revolutions=3, data=Duncan)
    scatter3d(prestige ~ income + education, fit=c("linear", "additive"),
              data=Prestige)
    Sys.sleep(5)
    scatter3d(prestige ~ income + education | type,
              radius=(1 + women)^(1/3), data=Prestige)
}
```

Will give you pretty elaborate 3d scatter plot:

[image: interactive]